# Which "value" has an un-init value?

Tags: c++, variables, init

I've this [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/349323265f4c31db):

```
double val1;
double val2 = 0.0;

if(val1 != val2) {
    cout << "different: " << val1 << " | " << val2 << endl;
}
```

which enter to the `if-statement`. I think that `val1` doesn't get 0.0 by default (i.e. NULL). Which value does it get so? I always thought 0.0 was by default...

Comment: Whatever happens to be on the stack at that location. There is no default-initialization for automatic variables.

Comment: Well, you always thought wrong.

Comment: The value `0.0` does not equal `NULL`.

Comment: It is 0.0 by default in some other languages, but not in C++.

Comment: compiling with debug flags may also make it 0 but not on release. In general in c++. Always initialize your variables (at least primitive datatypes).

Comment: #define NULL 1.23

Comment: @UKMonkey it shouldn't make a difference. 1.23 is also some value like 0.0. If you compare your pointers to `NULL`, then somewhere before you have to set them to `NULL` or return `NULL` which turns out, that it doesn't matter what the actual value of `NULL` itself is.

Comment: @molbdnilo: I know of no language where a `null` is equal to a floating point literal 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local non-static variables that are not initialized will have an *indeterminate* value, and it will be seemingly random.

You should not use uninitialized local variables as that leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Local non-static *primitives* will have indeterminate values. A struct or a class will be default-constructed, and what is and is not initialized depends on the class or struct default constructor definition.

Comment: But why if I print it (cout) it print 0? cout default behaviour on indeterminate value?

Comment: @paizza, indeterminate *doesn't* mean *non-zero*. It means it can have any value, zero included (but not guaranteed).

Comment: @paizza it can also be 0 in some circumstances (like when compiling in debug mode) but this is not guaranteed. Different compilers or even a different compilation mode with your compiler can change this. So you should not rely on it being 0 without explicitly setting it to 0.